# WPF binding different Shapes to a DataTemplate in an ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatemplate, drawing2d

I'd like to bind different System.Windows.Shapes.Shape to a DataTemplate in an ItemsControl.
I have the followng ItemsControl drawing shapes on a Canvas based on an array with positions and shape informations:

```
<ItemsControl Width="800" ItemsSource="{Binding ShapesPositionArray}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Name="sequenceCanvas" Width="800" Height="800" ClipToBounds="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Ellipse  Width="5" Height="5" Fill="Black"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

If I bind with a Shape like Ellipse (like the example) or Rectangle or Polygon it is perfectly working, but I need to have at the same time different shapes, like Polygons and Ellipses.
I tried to associate the DataTemplate to an object PartShape of type Shapes using a ContentControl:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding PartShape}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

The PartShape on the in VM is an object like this:

```
public System.Windows.Shapes.Shape PartShape
{
    get
    {
        System.Windows.Shapes.Shape r = new System.Windows.Shapes.Ellipse();
        r.Width = 20;
        r.Height = 5;
        return r;
    }
}
```

The binding is ok and gives no error, but it does not work, it draws nothing on canvas.
How could I do?

Thanks.

Comment: you didn't set Fill or Stroke. the shape is there but not visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to colorize the shape. it is added but not visible.

```
System.Windows.Shapes.Shape r = new System.Windows.Shapes.Ellipse 
{
    Width = 20,
    Height = 5,
    Fill = Brushes.Blue
};

public System.Windows.Shapes.Shape PartShape
{
    get { return r; }
}
```